# ' Sequence contains no elements' exception when initializing ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a problem with Ninject which I have not seen before and don't know how to fix. I am using the MVC NuGet package for MVC 5.

In my NinjectWebCommon.cs, there is the following method:

```
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }
```

However, it falls over when trying to execute the last line, complaining that the "sequence contains no elements". I was previously using Unity for DI but have changed to Ninject.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, M

Comment: Not to worry, found the answer. I had two NinjectWebCommon.cs files on the go.

Comment: I have only one NinjectWebCommon.cs file in the whole solution but still getting same issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993001/server-error-in-application-sequence-contains-no-elements-after-refactori worked for me

Answer (score 27):

In my case, my project had two NinjectWebCommon.cs folders with the same/similar content.
Dropping the folder has resolved the issue.

Comment: had multiple projects referencing ninject, after reinstalling library did not notice new NinjectWebCommon.cs. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15):

I faced this type of error while preparing a new solution by replacing File Name and other text in Entire solution.

Everything was perfect like buld the application.

But when i go to run the application it says me "Sequence contains no elements" error.

And finally i finally resolve that issue by using following.....

1. open every project folder by right click on the project >> Then select "Open Folder in File Explorer
2. Remove 'bin' and 'obj' folder
3. Clean Entire project
4. Build application
5. and finally run the application.

Hopefully, it will work for you....

Thanks...

Comment: I was trying every method on the internet sooo desperately, your answer too, and then, shazam! it all started to work again, Thank you so much.

Comment: Five years later, this answer helped me AGAIN. I wish the question's owner would have accepted it. Right on. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

For my two penneth and related to @Pavan's post. I started receiving the error after renaming an assembly. I had the old DLL lingering in the bin folder. Cleaning the solution didn't fix it. I had to go in and delete the contents of bin by hand.

Comment: Thats an important answer and a more possible solution to the problem. Why would anybody normally have the NinjectWebCommon files in a single project:)

Comment: This solved it for me.  I refactored my project and changed the name of the assembly.  When I published to Production, the production bin folder contained the dll with the old name, and hence forth I had 2 NinjectWebCommons wrecking my day.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a dupe of this question: [Ninject + MVC3 = InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160946/ninject-mvc3-invalidoperationexception-sequence-contains-no-elements)

TL;DR - make sure you clear out all old dlls when you publish your site.

Answer (score 0):

An additional explanation detail to extend the helpful answer by @Greg_B:

A reference to another project in the solution that also uses Ninject. Removing this reference solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this because I was trying to use version 5.0.0 of `Castle.Core` with version 3.3.5 of `Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy`, but that version of DynamicProxy only supports up to version 4.4.0 of `Castle.Core`

Downgrading to version 4.4.0 of `Castle.Core` fixed the problem for me