# Publish Azure service leads to 'Sequence contains no elements'

Tags: azure, publish, azure-worker-roles

I created *Azure Worker Role* project in Visual Studio 2015. When i start this project locally (via emulator) it works good. But when i try to publish this  worker role to Azure Cloud i receive these messages in *Microsoft Azure Activity Log*:

> 2:33:13 - Warning: There are package validation warnings.
>
> 2:33:13 - Sequence contains no elements

Publish status in *Microsoft Azure Activity Log* is *Failed*.

How to fix the problem and publish to azure? Why this problem happens?

Comment: Similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480411/erro-on-ninject-sequence-contains-no-elements    However you really need to add more details to your question as it is hard to work it out with the little information you have given

Comment: @Dijkgraaf 

Thanks but looks like author speak about WebRole in your link, my question is about WorkerRole. - Solution provided in thie link doesn't work since there is no such option "Remove additional files at destination"at all.

I think i provide enough info. What details you suggest to add?

Comment: Look at all the files in your solution that you are publishing and see if you can see anything amiss in them.  If you cannot see anything at least give us the structure of your solution (what files are included)

Comment: Restating the Windows resolve that issue on my machine.

Comment: @Vladimir thanks for comment (+1). After some steps: cleaning VS solution, restarting VS, restarting PC (my be some other steps) the problem was gone. But i don't know exactly what was the root o the problem and how to solve the problem

Comment: Probably has something to do with the similar issue https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/896, more like a minor bug within the Azure SDK.

Comment: For me, running Visual Studio as administrator resolved this issue.

Comment: After have the same problem - in order to remove that you should restart PC and run VS as Admin ) that would solve the problem for good